# Error running coral.cloudiot.core apperas suddenly

Tags: jwt, mqtt, gcloud, paho, google-coral

I am using the [coral.cloudiot.core](https://coral.ai/docs/reference/enviro/coral.cloudiot.core/) class ([install instructions](https://github.com/google-coral/project-cloud-monitor/tree/master/edge)). This is a high level API for [paho-mqtt](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/).

Please find a simplified version of my code below:

```
with CloudIot("./cloud_config.ini", config_section='DEFAULT') as cloud:
    while True:

        """if a defined if clause evalutes to True, 
        the following method is executed."""

        cloud.publish_message(message)
```

- Port 443 is used for the communication with the gcloud iot hub.
- I tried qos = 0 and 1
- systemctl is used to run the code.
- The scripts sends up to 48 messages per minute.
- ntp port is blocked by firewall (htpdate is used with crontab 5 * * * *)

After sometime the following error message accrues.

```
Mar 08 03:17:33 mocha-orange systemd[1]: Started ANN Client Detection.
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]: Exception in thread Thread-1:
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:     self.run()
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/coral/cloudiot/core.py", line 196, in _token_update_loop
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:     username='unused', password=self._create_jwt())
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/coral/cloudiot/core.py", line 225, in _create_jwt
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:     return self._jwt_inst.encode(token, self._private_key, algorithm=self._algorithm)
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 65, in encode
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:     json_payload, key, algorithm, headers, json_encoder
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 114, in encode
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:     signature = alg_obj.sign(signing_input, key)
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/coral/cloudiot/ecc608.py", line 132, in sign
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:     return ecc608_hw_sign(msg)
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/coral/cloudiot/ecc608.py", line 81, in ecc608_hw_sign
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]:     assert status == 0
Mar 09 07:18:30 mocha-orange start_service_client[3957]: AssertionError
```

I do not understand how to solve this problem. I appreciate any hint.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the Coral board but familiar with Cloud IoT. It's possible (!?) that you've not correctly configured the device to access Cloud IoT. The assertion arises in `ecc608` (which appears to implement the crypto chip on your board) when it tries to sign messages to send. Specifically, did you follow these steps: https://github.com/google-coral/project-cloud-monitor/tree/master/edge#cloud-iot-core? Did you add the device's ES256 public key to Cloud IoT? Did you try the `enabled()` method? That suggests it checks connectivity.

Comment: The device seems correctly configured, as the service works smooth for most of the time and i did follow the steps descried in https://github.com/google-coral/project-cloud-monitor/tree/master/edge#cloud-iot-core. After a couple of hours in use the above error accrues.

Comment: Aha! Without seeing the source code, it's possible that the Coral library is issuing a short (few hours) expiry JWT. The JWT expires and so your code fails. You could test this by shortening your while loop from forever to an hour (or whatever time you're confident you get) and then restarting `with CloudIoT...` to force a recreation of the JWT.

Comment: Another option is that you're exceeding quota on Cloud IoT. You can check this using Cloud Console: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/cloudiot.googleapis.com

Comment: The quota is not exceeded. What seems strange to me is the fact that the  coral.cloudiot.core takes care of the renewal of the jwt token every 50 minutes and the jwt token is valid vor 60 min. see line 188 and 205 (https://bitbucket.org/snippets/oculyticsgmbh/5Lzndx). According to the journalctl after a couple of hours (https://bitbucket.org/snippets/oculyticsgmbh/n7z5b5).

Comment: What device are you running this on?

Comment: Your logic is sound. I can also see that the `_token_update_loop` is ahead in the stacktrace. Do you have access to `ecc608.py` too? Can you trace into `ecc608_hw_sign` when the error arises at #81? Does this always fail at this time when it tries to renew the JWT? Perhaps it wasn't tested correctly and this process is incorrect?

Comment: I run this on the google coral DevBoard. Yes i do have access to the ecc608.py. The error seems to accrue with the renewal of the JWT, but most of the time the renewal seems to work.